# How to stack two item using Linear Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to stack two different charts in one Linear Layout. Here is my code. I want when user choose the progress chart, the chart will convert from `com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart` to `com.example.imed.Progress.CustomCalenderView` and vice versa.

I set the visibility in the JAVA class. However, the problem is, is it possible to stack these two different charts in a Linear Layout? If yes, can you help me to fix the code segment below?
I already add orientation to vertical but these two chart does not stack to each other.

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>

    <com.example.imed.Progress.CustomCalenderView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/custom_calendar_view">
    </com.example.imed.Progress.CustomCalenderView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean overlaying the `View`s, then no, it is not possible using a `LinearLayout`.

To achieve this, you need to use, for example, `FrameLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`.

The recommended layout to create your UI is the [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout). It is highly flexible and basically combines the function of any other layout and adds even more.
Refer to the linked docs to find out more about `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. I tried to use the Relative Layout instead. And its work! :D Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you only need to have  the next form

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_wrap"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>


     <com.example.imed.Progress.CustomCalenderView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_wrap"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/custom_calendar_view">
        </com.example.imed.Progress.CustomCalenderView>
```

The CustomCalenderView should not be in  match_parent's height

Comment: I try this code, but the both item does not stack each other. It moves to the next line instead. Same as the picture that I attached. Thank you for helping btw :D

Comment: Change the xml to constraintlayout. it is a little better. Do you know how it uses?